# Running expo project in (window subsystem linux) inside of (windows 11)

Tags: android, react-native, expo, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm using **(wsl 2)** for development because of **(bun)** building tool because it's now available yet on windows, so I tried to run `bunx expo start` to start my **react native + expo project**, when I tried to connect my **expo project** on my android device using **expo go** by scanning the **qr code** I've got this error:

**uncaught error java.net.sockettimeoutexception failed to connect to /172.27.73.14 (port 8081) from /192.168.1.128 (port 33518)**

`172.27.73.14` is my **wsl** ip address, but in my **windows** is `192.168.1.111` and on my **android** device is `192.168.1.128`.

Does anyone know how can I connect my **expo project** that running on my **wsl** to my **android** device?